# Android:javascrpit interface

Tags: android

1.if load the ULR it correctly showing the webpage.After getting the values  javascript.It show only value to inserted value  in webpage not full content.

My code here

```
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);


    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // String user = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text)).getText().toString();
            String javascript = "javascript: document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Hello ";
            //   String javascript="javascript: document.getElementById('riderName').innerHTML='Hello "+tickectname+"!';";
            view.loadUrl(javascript);
        }
    });
    refreshWebView();
    return view;
}


private void refreshWebView() {
    mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    refreshWebView();
}
```

}

when load the url  it load correct url after i inserting value to             String javascript = "javascript: document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Hello ";

it load only hello..

any help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
String javascript = "javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Hello'})()";
view.loadUrl(javascript);
```

Comment: Thanks ,  ....thanks....This thinks i get wrong ...Our answer helped for me

Comment: Hi i have another issues how to set image in src in image path in html. i have encoded image

Comment: @jayaoriya, you can't set local i.e device image in `src` if image hosted on server you can set it like this `document.getElementById("imageid").src="absolute path to image on server";`

Comment: you have not accepted answer yet, tick my answer :)

Comment: HI have doubt in javascrpit